# Making POST request using Curl, not working

Tags: php, curl

I want to make a POST request to get schedule of a train number from this page: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html

I'm using this code but it is NOT working. The resulting error shown in attachment below. **What could be the problem?**
PS: I've got the cgi path and arguments as in $data using Firebug

```
$data = array('lccp_trnname' => '14553', 'getIt' => 'Get Schedule');

    $ch = curl_init();
    $useragent= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // set user agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_trnnum_cgi.cgi');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $txResult = curl_exec($ch);

    print "$txResult\n";
```

[image]:

Comment: http://www.indianrail.gov.in use in your site is illegal .and your URL is also wrong.FAILED IN CHK ENV 0 erro ris there

Comment: Added referer ("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html") to your code too and this does not seem to help. Can't see any form values missed... they have put protection in place to stop external requests though. I would recommend finding a different (more open) data source.

Comment: @Ing got it; please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things:

a referrer
an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" POST data

```
$params = 'lccp_trnname='.urlencode('14553').'&getIt='.urlencode('Get Schedule');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html");
```

Comment: Brilliant! The third line is not required. The first line did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have permission to programatically consume the data on that site......

The problem is the way you pass the post data to cURL.

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in array form to work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Try encoding the post data yourself and passing it as a string:

```
$data = array('lccp_trnname' => '14553', 'getIt' => 'Get Schedule');

$fields_string = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

Then set the option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```